# OpenAI GPT-3 API: Fine tune a fine tuned model?

Tags: transformer-model, openai-api, fine-tuning, gpt-3

The OpenAI documentation for the `model` attribute in the fine-tune API states a bit confusingly:

> **model**
>
> The name of the base model to fine-tune. You can select one of "ada", "babbage", "curie", "davinci", or a fine-tuned model created after 2022-04-21.

My question: is it better to fine-tune a base model or a fine-tuned model?

I created a fine-tune model from `ada` with file `mydata1K.jsonl`:

```
ada + mydata1K.jsonl --> ada:ft-acme-inc-2022-06-25
```

Now I have a bigger file of samples `mydata2K.jsonl` that I want to use to improve the fine-tuned model.
In this second round of fine-tuning, is it better to fine-tune `ada` again or to fine-tune my fine-tuned model `ada:ft-acme-inc-2022-06-25`?  I'm assuming this is possible because my fine tuned model is created after 2022-04-21.

```
ada + mydata2K.jsonl --> better-model
```

or

```
ada:ft-acme-inc-2022-06-25 + mydata2K.jsonl --> even-better-model?
```

Comment: I found the answer on the openai forum:  https://community.openai.com/t/continuous-fine-tuning-best-practices/18942
"If you have already fine-tuned a model for your task and now have additional training data that you would like to incorporate, you can continue fine-tuning from the model. This creates a model that has learned from all of the training data without having to re-train from scratch."

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

It looks like fine-tuning a fine-tuned model is not supported anymore, as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/can-i-continue-fine-tuning-a-model-that-has-already-been-fine-tuned):

> ##### Can I continue fine-tuning a model that has already been fine-tuned?
>
> No, we do not currently support continuing the fine-tuning process
> once a job has finished. We plan to support this in the near future.

---

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/continue-fine-tuning-from-a-fine-tuned-model):

> If you have already fine-tuned a model for your task and now have
> additional training data that you would like to incorporate, you can
> continue fine-tuning from the model. **This creates a model that has
> learned from all of the training data without having to re-train from
> scratch.**
>
> To do this, pass in the fine-tuned model name when creating a new
> fine-tuning job (e.g., `-m curie:ft-<org>-<date>`). Other training
> parameters do not have to be changed, however if your new training
> data is much smaller than your previous training data, you may find it
> useful to reduce `learning_rate_multiplier` by a factor of 2 to 4.

#### Which option to choose?

You're asking about two options:

- Option 1: `ada + bigger-training-dataset.jsonl`
- Option 2: `ada:ft-acme-inc-2022-06-25 + additional-training-dataset.jsonl`

The documentation says nothing about which option is better *in terms of which would yield better results*.

However...

#### Choose Option 2

Why?

> When training a fine-tuned model, the total tokens used will be billed
> according to our [training rates](https://openai.com/api/pricing/#quotas).

If you choose Option 1, you'll pay for some tokens in your training dataset twice. First when doing fine-tuning with initial training dataset, second when doing fine-tuning with bigger training dataset (i.e., `bigger-training-dataset.jsonl` = `initial-training-dataset.jsonl` + `additional-training-dataset.jsonl`).

**It's better to continue fine-tuning from a fine-tuned model because you'll pay only for tokens in your additional training dataset.**

Read more about [fine-tuning pricing calculation](https://openai.com/api/pricing/#faq-fine-tuning-pricing-calculation).

Comment: Hello. I have a question, if in the training data that I gave to the first model I find that there are a few errors (suppose 5% of the data set) should I retrain a new model or extend the training of this one, only with that 5% of the data that was wrong and already corrected.

Comment: @suribe06 Hi! Fine-tuning might not be the best option for your case. First, fine-tuning is not even the right approach if you want to get an exact answer (i.e., a fact) to a specific question. To see why, read my previous answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76558875/10347145) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000154/openai-gpt-3-api-how-do-i-make-sure-answers-are-from-a-customized-fine-tuning/75192794#75192794)). Second, this is probably one of the biggest downsides of fine-tuning. You can't just "replace" wrong or outdated data.

Comment: @suribe06 [continuing] You have two options, as you've already figured out. Either you continue fine-tuning a fine-tuned model or do fine-tuning from scratch. **If you chose fine-tuning over semantic search (i.e., the embeddings approach) in the first place**, then I suggest you pick the second option (i.e., fine-tuning from scratch). Why? **Because if you fine-tune a fine-tuned model, the model will have two sets of data (wrong or outdated and a new one), which will probably make the model hallucinate even more!**

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I am making a first approach to a classification model using LLM, as shown in the OpenAI [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/classification).

Comment: @suribe06 Then follow the example in the documentation. I've never done classifications. I just know that the [Classifications API endpoint](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/deprecation-log) is deprecated. Regarding your question, I really don't have hands-on experience, so I can't give you a suggestion on whether you should continue fine-tuning a fine-tuned model or do fine-tuning from scratch for classification purposes.