# OpenAI Embeddings API: How to get an embedding and calculate cosine similarity?

Tags: python, openai-api

I have an OpenAI embedding generated from their API.

I see examples of putting that vector into Postgres or Sqlite and then running a query against it.

I'm looking for simple code in python where I can use a text string and see how close the cosine distance for that text. I believe that cosine distance is used in databases because it is simpler to calculate: would using Euclidean distance be a more accurate estimate of the "closeness" of the string? If there is a better distance function to run I'm interested in seeing that as well.

Answer (score 4):

#### Regarding cosine similarity calculation

See my [past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75192794/10347145), especially the following part (i.e., STEP 3):

> We need to calculate an embedding vector for the input so that we can
> compare the input with a given "fact" and see how similar these two
> texts are. Actually, we compare the embedding vector of the input with
> the embedding vector of the "fact". Then we compare the input with the
> second "fact", the third "fact", the fourth "fact", etc. Run
> `get_cosine_similarity.ipynb`.
>
> **get_cosine_similarity.ipynb**
>
> ```
> import openai
> from openai.embeddings_utils import cosine_similarity
> import pandas as pd
> import os
>
> openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
>
> my_model = 'text-embedding-ada-002'
> my_input = '<INSERT_INPUT_HERE>'
>
> def get_embedding(model: str, text: str) -> list[float]:
>     result = openai.Embedding.create(
>       model = my_model,
>       input = my_input
>     )
>     return result['data'][0]['embedding']
>
> input_embedding_vector = get_embedding(my_model, my_input)
>
> df = pd.read_csv('companies_embeddings.csv')
> df['embedding'] = df['embedding'].apply(eval).apply(np.array)
> df['similarity'] = df['embedding'].apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(x, input_embedding_vector))
> df
> ```
>
> The code above will take the input and compare it with the first fact.
> It will save the calculated similarity of the two in a new column
> named `'similarity'`. Then it will take the second fact, the third
> fact, the fourth fact, etc.

#### Regarding which distance function to choose

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/which-distance-function-should-i-use):

> ##### Which distance function should I use?
>
> **We recommend [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).**
> The choice of distance function typically doesn’t matter much.
>
> OpenAI embeddings are normalized to length 1, which means that:
>
> - Cosine similarity can be computed slightly faster using just a dot
>   product
> - Cosine similarity and Euclidean distance will result in the
>   identical rankings

Answer (score 0):

With the release of openai-python v1.0.0, some modules were renamed and data structures changed ([migration discussion here](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742)). The snipped provided can be migrated using the example described at [Azure OpenAI Service Embeddings Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/tutorials/embeddings?tabs=python-new%2Ccommand-line&pivots=programming-language-python#tabpanel_5_python-new).