# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: Can I fine-tune the gpt-3.5-turbo model?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a SQL table containing huge data, need to train the SQL table data to ChatGPT using Chat Completion API.

I tried of generating a SQL query using ChatGPT, but that doesn't work as expected. Sometimes it generates inappropriate query.

Comment: Why is this question closed? I can see other fine-tuning questions from other deep-learning models.

Comment: very similar question was asked here (and closed): https://stackoverflow.com/q/75811594/11107541

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE: 22 August 2023**

Fine-tuning for GPT-3.5 is now available, as stated in the official [OpenAI blog](https://openai.com/blog/gpt-3-5-turbo-fine-tuning-and-api-updates):

> Fine-tuning for GPT-3.5 Turbo is now available, with fine-tuning for
> GPT-4 coming this fall. This update gives developers the ability to
> customize models that perform better for their use cases and run these
> custom models at scale. Early tests have shown a fine-tuned version of
> GPT-3.5 Turbo can match, or even outperform, base GPT-4-level
> capabilities on certain narrow tasks. As with all our APIs, data sent
> in and out of the fine-tuning API is owned by the customer and is not
> used by OpenAI, or any other organization, to train other models.

Also, two new models (i.e., `davinci-002` and `babbage-002`) were introduced as replacements for GPT-3 models (`davinci`, `curie`, `babbage`, and `ada`) as those GPT-3 models will be turned off on January 4th, 2024. Consequently, if you take a look at the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/what-models-can-be-fine-tuned) now, you'll see the following:

> ##### What models can be fine-tuned?
>
> Fine-tuning is currently available for the following models:
>
> - `gpt-3.5-turbo-0613` (recommended)
> - `babbage-002`
> - `davinci-002`
>
> We expect
> `gpt-3.5-turbo` to be the right model for most users in terms of results
> and ease of use, unless you are migrating a legacy fine-tuned model.

*Note: GPT-3 models were already removed from the list, but they should still be available for fine-tuning until January 4th, 2024.*

---

**You can't fine-tune the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model.**

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/what-models-can-be-fine-tuned):

> ##### What models can be fine-tuned?
>
> Fine-tuning is currently only available
> for the following base models: `davinci`, `curie`, `babbage`, and `ada`. These
> are the original models that do not have any instruction following
> training (like `text-davinci-003` does for example). You are also able
> to [continue fine-tuning a fine-tuned model](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/continue-fine-tuning-from-a-fine-tuned-model) to add additional data
> without having to start from scratch.

Comment: How can we use completion API with Fine tuning effectively to answer all user queries from DB?

Comment: You can only fine-tune GPT-3 models (e.g., `text-davinci-003`). But... **Fine-tuning is not what you need to do.** You need to calculate embeddings and cosine similarity. See [Customize (fine-tune) OpenAI model: How to make sure answers are from customized (fine-tuning) dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000154/customize-fine-tune-openai-model-how-to-make-sure-answers-are-from-customized/75192794)

Comment: Update: The `text-davinci-003` model is not available for fine-tuning anymore. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**gpt-3.5 models are not available for fine-tuning right now.
But gpt3 models can be fine-tuned.**

Fine-tuning is currently only available for the following base models: davinci, curie, babbage, and ada. These are the original models that do not have any instruction following training (like text-davinci-003 does for example).

Please follow the documentation for details. https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

Answer (score 1):

**As of August 22nd 2023, you can now fine-tune all GPT-3.5 Turbo models:**
https://openai.com/blog/gpt-3-5-turbo-fine-tuning-and-api-updates

Your use case for fine-tuning to inadvertently ‘train’ the model on your database schema via examples ***does*** seem like a valid fine-tuning use case.

However, worth pointing out: Fine-tuning is **NOT** the mechanism for training the model on large datasets to improve its knowledge base / ‘pre-trained data’ - to handle those types of use cases I would suggest to instead utilize a vector database to store that contextual data (can use Embedding model to convert text/documents to vectors), utilize a retriever mechanism (eg [LangChain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/introduction)) to retrieve relevant context for a given query, and then finally include that retrieved context along with the original query in your prompt sent to chat/completion API of LLM.