# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: Can I fine-tune a GPT-3.5 model?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have fine-tuned an `openai` language model (`curie`) and was able to access the model via `openai.Completion.create` method but I could not access the fine-tuned model via `openai.ChatCompletion.create`.

By researching a bit I have found out that the problem is not in the fine-tuning but in the fact that the original `curie` model is not accessible via `openai.ChatCompletion.create`.

By looping over these models:

```
models = ['gpt-3.5-turbo', 'davinci', 'curie', 'babbage', 'ada']
```

I found out that only `gpt-3.5-turbo` model is accessible via `openai.ChatCompletion.create` and it is not accessible via `openai.Completion.create`. In contrast, the remaining four models are accessible via `openai.Completion.create` but are not accessible via `openai.ChatCompletion.create`.

So, my first question if someone can confirm my finding? Is what I found out written somewhere on `openai` documentation pages?

My second question is if it is possible to fine-tune a model that supports Chat / Dialogue?

For example on the official page I see that:

> Fine-tuning is currently only available for the following base models:
> davinci, curie, babbage, and ada.

So, did I get it right that we can only fine-tune models that do not support Chat / Dialogue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: How to fine-tune the gpt-3.5-turbo model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729386/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-how-to-fine-tune-the-gpt-3-5-turbo-model)

Comment: No, it does not answer my question. I know how to fine-tune gpt-3.5-turbo model.

Comment: Regarding your second question, please check chatllama ```https://github.com/juncongmoo/chatllama```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

> I found out that only `gpt-3.5-turbo` model is accessible via
> `openai.ChatCompletion.create` and it is not accessible via
> `openai.Completion.create`. In contrast, the remaining four models are
> accessible via `openai.Completion.create` but are not accessible via
> `openai.ChatCompletion.create`.
>
> So, my first question if someone can confirm my finding?

**Answer 1:**

Yes, correct. The reason why this is the case is that the `gpt-3.5.-turbo` model is a GPT-3.5 model. All the other models you mentioned (i.e., `davinci`, `curie`, `babbage`, and `ada`) are GPT-3 models.

[GPT-3.5 models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) use a different API endpoint than [GPT-3 models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create). This is not explicitly written in the documentation, but it's very clear if you read the whole documentation.

---

**Question 2:**

> My second question is if it is possible to fine-tune a model that
> supports Chat / Dialogue?

**Answer 2:**

No, it's [not possible](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/what-models-can-be-fine-tuned). You want to fine-tune a GPT-3.5 model, which is not possible as of March 2023. Also, it doesn't seem this will change in the near future, if ever. Why?

I strongly recommend you to read the official [OpenAI article](https://openai.com/blog/how-should-ai-systems-behave) on how ChatGPT's behavior is shaped to understand why you can't fine-tune a GPT-3.5 model. I want to emphasize that the article doesn't discuss specifically the fine-tuning of a GPT-3.5 model, or better yet, its inability to do so, but rather ChatGPT's behavior. **It's important to emphasize that ChatGPT is not the same as the GPT-3.5 model, but ChatGPT uses chat models, which GPT-3.5 belongs to, along with GPT-4 models.**

As stated in the article:

> Unlike ordinary software, our models are massive neural networks.
> Their behaviors are learned from a broad range of data, not programmed
> explicitly. /.../ An initial “pre-training” phase comes first, in
> which the model learns to predict the next word in a sentence,
> informed by its exposure to lots of Internet text (and to a vast array
> of perspectives). This is followed by a second phase in which we
> “fine-tune” our models to narrow down system behavior.
>
> **First, we “pre-train” models by having them predict what comes next in
> a big dataset that contains parts of the Internet.** They might learn to
> complete the sentence “instead of turning left, she turned ___.” By
> learning from billions of sentences, our models learn grammar, many
> facts about the world, and some reasoning abilities. They also learn
> some of the biases present in those billions of sentences.
>
> **Then, we “fine-tune” these models on a more narrow dataset that we
> carefully generate with human reviewers who follow guidelines that we
> provide them.** /.../ Then, while they are in use, the models generalize
> from this reviewer feedback in order to respond to a wide array of
> specific inputs provided by a given user.

Visual representation ([source](https://openai.com/blog/how-should-ai-systems-behave)):

[image: Screenshot]

**As you can see, chat models (i.e., GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models) are already "fine-tuned" by the OpenAI. This is the reason why you can only fine-tune base models: `davinci`, `curie`, `babbage`, and `ada`. These are the original models that do not have any instruction following training.**