# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: Can I use a fine-tuned GPT-3 model with the GPT-3.5 API endpoint (error: "Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions)")?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

After we create a fine-tuned model, how can we use it at /v1/chat/completions? We tried this but it gave an error

```
curl --location 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "model": "davinci:ft-xxx-inc:6302f74d2000001f00f80919-2023-04-15-00-47-48",
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "How to use apple vision api to recognize text? any example?"
        }
    ]
}'
// Error
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions)",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you wanted to fine-tune the GPT-3 `davinci` model and use it with the GPT-3.5 API endpoint.

You can fine-tune the `davinci` model as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/what-models-can-be-fine-tuned):

> Fine-tuning is currently only available for the following base models:
> `davinci`, `curie`, `babbage`, and `ada`. These are the original models that
> do not have any instruction following training (like `text-davinci-003`
> does for example). You are also able to [continue fine-tuning a
> fine-tuned model](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/continue-fine-tuning-from-a-fine-tuned-model) to add additional data without having to start from
> scratch.

But... **The `davinci` model is not compatible with the `/v1/chat/completions` API endpoint** as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/model-endpoint-compatibility):

| ENDPOINT | MODEL NAME |
| --- | --- |
| /v1/chat/completions | gpt-4, gpt-4-0613, gpt-4-32k, gpt-4-32k-0613, gpt-3.5-turbo, gpt-3.5-turbo-0613, gpt-3.5-turbo-16k, gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613 |
| /v1/completions | text-davinci-003, text-davinci-002, text-curie-001, text-babbage-001, text-ada-001 |
| /v1/edits | text-davinci-edit-001, code-davinci-edit-001 |
| /v1/audio/transcriptions | whisper-1 |
| /v1/audio/translations | whisper-1 |
| /v1/fine-tunes | davinci, curie, babbage, ada |
| /v1/embeddings | text-embedding-ada-002, text-search-ada-doc-001 |
| /v1/moderations | text-moderation-stable, text-moderation-latest |

Comment: Do you know if there are plans to support fine-tuning in the chat completions API? With the addition of function calls for structured data, it seems like fine-tuned models can get very powerful when building a custom API.

Comment: @AlejandroCorredor I don't think it'll be possible to fine-tune a GPT-3.5 or GPT-4 model in the near future, if ever. Please read my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75730445) to see why.

Comment: That makes sense. What does seem possible then is for OpenAI to let you choose your own fine-tuned model (based on davinci for example) when using the chat completions API.

Comment: @AlejandroCorredor What do you mean? You can't use a fine-tuned model with the Chat Completions API. You can use a fine-tuned model with the Completions API only.

Comment: Right, I know that's the constraint right now. I'm just saying that it would be great to be able to use a fine-tuned GPT-3 model like davinci with the Chat Completions API. Theoretically it seems possible since ChatGPT is just a GPT-3.x model fine-tuned to better handle chat, right? Basically I'm just trying to validate that my thought process is at least in the right direction.

There doesn't seem to be a clear technical reason why OpenAI couldn't support something like what I'm describing.

Comment: @AlejandroCorredor I see at least one practical reason not to allow the use of the fine-tuned GPT-3 model with the GPT-3.5 API endpoint. I've been active on StackOverflow answering questions about the OpenAI API since December 2022. When the GPT-3.5 API came out, there was a huge misunderstanding among the users. People were trying to use a GPT-3 model with the GPT-3.5 API endpoint or a GPT-3.5 model with the GPT-3 API endpoint. It'll be even more complicated to explain to people that they can use a fine-tuned GPT-3 with the GPT-3.5 API endpoint but not a vanilla GPT-3 model.