# OpenAI Embeddings API: How embeddings work?

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

There are quite a few tutorials on `embeddings` in OpenAI. I can't understand how they work.

Referring to https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/what-are-embeddings , an `embedding` is a `vector` or `list`. A string is passed to an `embedding` model and the model returns a number (in simplest terms). I can use this number(s).

If I use a simple string to get its `embeddings`, I get a massive list

```
result = get_embedding("I live in space", engine = "textsearchcuriedoc001mc")
```

`result` when printed

```
[5.4967957112239674e-05,
 -0.01301578339189291,
 -0.002223075833171606,
 0.013594076968729496,
 -0.027540158480405807,
 0.008867159485816956,
 0.009403547272086143,
 -0.010987567715346813,
 0.01919262297451496,
 0.022209804505109787,
 -0.01397960539907217,
 -0.012806257233023643,
 -0.027908924967050552,
 0.013074451126158237,
 0.024942029267549515,
 0.0200139675289392 , ..... -> truncated this much, much, much longer list
```

Question 1 - how is this massive list correlated with my 4-word text?

Question 2 -

I create `embeddings` of the text I want to use in query. Note that it is exactly the same as the text of original content `I live in space`

```
queryembedding = get_embedding(
        'I live in space',
        engine="textsearchcuriequery001mc"
    )
queryembedding
```

When I run `cosine similarity` , the value is `0.42056650555103214`.

```
similarity = cosine_similarity(embeddings_of_i_live,queryembedding)
similarity
```

I get value `0.42056650555103214`

Shouldn't the value be `1` to indicate identical value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1:

> How is this massive list correlated with my 4-word text?

A1: Let's say you want to use the OpenAI `text-embedding-ada-002` model. **No matter what your input is, you will always get a 1536-dimensional embedding vector (i.e., there are 1536 numbers inside).** You are probably familiar with 3-dimensional space (i.e., X, Y, Z). Well, this is a 1536-dimensional space, which is very hard to imagine. Why are there exactly 1536 numbers inside the embedding vector? Because the `text-embedding-ada-002` model has an output dimension of [1536](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/second-generation-models). It's pre-defined.

Q2:

> I create embeddings of the text I want to use in the query. Note that it
> is exactly the same as the text of the original content: `I live in space`.
> When I run cosine similarity, the value is `0.42056650555103214`.
> Should the value be `1` to indicate an identical value?

A2: **Yes, the value should be `1` if you calculate cosine similarity between two identical texts.** See an example [here](https://tilores.io/cosine-similarity-online-tool?t1=I%20live%20in%20space&t2=I%20live%20in%20space).

For an example of semantic search based on embeddings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000154/openai-gpt-3-api-how-do-i-make-sure-answers-are-from-a-customized-fine-tuning/75192794#75192794).

Comment: strangely, I get `cosine similarity` value as `0.42056650555103214`  . I have updated the question

Comment: If you compare two identical pieces of text and you don't get a cosine similarity of 1 then something is wrong with your process.  Are your vectors the same? If they are, your are calculating cosine similarity wrongly.