# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: How do I make a fine-tuned GPT-3.5 model only answer from the fine-tuned data?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, fine-tuning

OpenAI now allows us to fine-tune GPT-3.5 models. I have tested and fine-tuned the model with my own dataset but the problem is the fine-tuned model generates the answer randomly, not correct based on my custom dataset.

Is there any way to make the model only answer from my own fine-tuned dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a completely wrong approach, as you've already figured out.

### Why doesn't the fine-tuned OpenAI model answer a specific question with a specific answer (i.e., fact) from the fine-tuning dataset?

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/when-to-use-fine-tuning):

> Some common use cases where fine-tuning can improve results:
>
> - Setting the style, tone, format, or other qualitative aspects
> - Improving reliability at producing a desired output
> - Correcting failures to follow complex prompts
> - Handling many edge cases in
>   specific ways
> - Performing a new skill or task that’s hard to articulate
>   in a prompt

**Fine-tuning is not about answering a specific question with a specific answer (i.e., fact) from the fine-tuning dataset.**

### What's the correct approach, then?

You need to implement a **vector similarity search**, as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/when-should-i-use-fine-tuning-vs-embeddings-with-retrieval):

> ##### When should I use fine-tuning vs embeddings with retrieval?
>
> Embeddings
> with retrieval is best suited for cases when you need to have a large
> database of documents with relevant context and information.
>
> By default OpenAI’s models are trained to be helpful generalist
> assistants. Fine-tuning can be used to make a model which is narrowly
> focused, and exhibits specific ingrained behavior patterns. Retrieval
> strategies can be used to make new information available to a model by
> providing it with relevant context before generating its response.
> Retrieval strategies are not an alternative to fine-tuning and can in
> fact be complementary to it.

A term that you most likely stumbled upon to this point if you're into AI is **RAG (i.e., Retrieval-Augmented Generation)**. Read [Nvidia's RAG explanation](https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/what-is-retrieval-augmented-generation/) to better understand what RAG is:

> To understand the latest advance in generative AI, imagine a
> courtroom.
>
> Judges hear and decide cases based on their general understanding of
> the law. Sometimes a case — like a malpractice suit or a labor dispute
> — requires special expertise, so judges send court clerks to a law
> library, looking for precedents and specific cases they can cite.
>
> Like a good judge, large language models (LLMs) can respond to a wide
> variety of human queries. But to deliver authoritative answers that
> cite sources, the model needs an assistant to do some research.
>
> The court clerk of AI is a process called retrieval-augmented
> generation, or RAG for short.

### Wait, what does a RAG have to do with vector similarity search?

**RAGs use vector similarity search under the hood.** Take a look at the visual representation of a RAG process below:

[image: Screenshot]
Image source: [An introduction to RAG and simple/ complex RAG by Chia Jeng Yang](https://medium.com/enterprise-rag/an-introduction-to-rag-and-simple-complex-rag-9c3aa9bd017b)

Information is extracted from data sources *(A)*, slashed into chunks *(B)*, transformed into vectors *(C)*, and inserted into a vector database *(D)*. When a user asks a question, its question is transformed into a vector *(1)*. This vector is then compared with vectors that are inside the vector database *(2)*. The most similar vectors *(3)* are passed to an LLM *(4)*, which then returns an answer to the user *(5)*.

This is how RAGs work. They use a vector similarity search under the hood.

### So, how do I achieve my goal?

You have at least the following three options if you want your LLM to answer a specific question with a specific answer (i.e., fact):

1. Custom solution (see my [past StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75192794/10347145)).
2. Using [LlamaIndex RAG](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [LangChain RAG](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/introduction.html) (see my [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/93uru3QmgAo) with corresponsing [code](https://github.com/rokbenko/ai-playground/tree/main/llamaindex-tutorials/2-GUI_travel_recommendation_RAG)).
3. Using the OpenAI [Assistants API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/overview/agents) (see my [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/F-KRs6vg4mM) with corresponding [code](https://github.com/rokbenko/ai-playground/tree/main/openai-tutorials/2-Build_personal_math_tutor)).

Comment: There is now more simpler alternative to embedding for small datasets which I used. i.e. Assistant APIs. Its quicker to get it to work with openai assistant apis.