# OpenAI API: What would be a good strategy to handle 80+ function calling?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

My business handles a variety of entities (job, invoice, quote, resource, vehicle, contact, person, message, alert, etc.).

My goal is to use OpenAI function calling to allow my users to ask "anything" about their data. If you roughly estimate 20 entities and 4 potential actions each, that's approximately 80 API calls I need to define in my prompt so GPT can select the one best matching the user's question.

Not only would this consume a significant number of tokens, but it might also confuse the engine.

What are some effective strategies to work around this issue?

Initially, I considered presenting users with a route so they can first select which area of my system they want to inquire about, in order to narrow it down. However, this defeats the purpose of being able to "ask for anything."

I'm also considering making an initial call to the OpenAI API to identify the entity from a predefined list, followed by a second call with a list of my APIs matching that entity. However, if the user's language doesn't match my predefined list, I may direct the logic down the wrong path. For example, "*What is Ryan's phone number?*" Is Ryan a resource? A person? A web user? What if the context needs switching because the user asks a follow-up question?

**-- Edit --**

After Rok's answer I think I need to precise I have over 2,000 customers who will be be asking questions about their own data. Each of these customers could have 100k CRM contacts, 100k jobs completed for these contacts, 100k invoices raised for these jobs etc...

Comment: I think openai recommends using fine tuning specifically for a case like this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Goal

The following part of your question is crucial:

> My goal is to use OpenAI function calling to allow my users to ask
> "anything" about their data.

In other words, **you want the user to get an exact answer (i.e., a fact) to a specific question from existing data sources**.

#### Problem

Using OpenAI function calling is not the right approach to achieve this, as you've already figured out, because of the reasons you mentioned in your question.

Also, **function calling would (likely) result in hallucinated outputs**. See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/function-calling):

> The basic sequence of steps for function calling is as follows:
>
> 1. Call the model with the user query and a set of functions defined in the functions parameter.
> 2. The model can choose to call a function; if so, the content will be a stringified JSON object adhering to your custom schema (**note: the
>    model may generate invalid JSON or hallucinate parameters**).
> 3. Parse the string into JSON in your code, and call your function with the provided arguments if they exist.
> 4. Call the model again by appending the function response as a new message, and let the model summarize the results back to the user.

Although OpenAI suggests solving the hallucination problem by setting a system message, it's still not the right approach for you.

#### Solution

**You need to implement semantic search.** You have two options:

**OPTION 1: Using [LlamaIndex](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [LangChain](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/index.html)**

Both enable you to connect OpenAI models with your existing data sources, as stated in the official [LlamaIndex documentation](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#why-llamaindex):

> At their core, LLMs offer a natural language interface between humans
> and inferred data. Widely available models come pre-trained on huge
> amounts of publicly available data, from Wikipedia and mailing lists
> to textbooks and source code.
>
> Applications built on top of LLMs often require augmenting these
> models with private or domain-specific data. Unfortunately, that data
> can be distributed across siloed applications and data stores. It’s
> behind APIs, in SQL databases, or trapped in PDFs and slide decks.
>
> That’s where LlamaIndex comes in.

**OPTION 2: Using the OpenAI [Embeddings API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/embeddings) endpoint**

See my [past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000154/openai-gpt-3-api-how-do-i-make-sure-answers-are-from-a-customized-fine-tuning/75192794#75192794). The flow is as follows:

1. Create a file or database with "facts" (i.e., data).
2. Calculate an embedding vector for every "fact".
3. Calculate an embedding vector for the input and compare it with all "fact" embedding vectors using cosine similarity.
4. Answer with the most similar "fact" if similarity is above your similarity threshold. Otherwise, answer with the OpenAI API.

If you choose the second option, you can use [Pinecone](https://www.pinecone.io/) for storing embedding vectors, as stated in the official [Pinecone article](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/vector-database/):

> Embeddings are generated by AI models (such as Large Language Models)
> and have a large number of attributes or features, making their
> representation challenging to manage. In the context of AI and machine
> learning, these features represent different dimensions of the data
> that are essential for understanding patterns, relationships, and
> underlying structures.
>
> **That is why we need a specialized database designed specifically for
> handling this type of data.** Vector databases like Pinecone fulfill
> this requirement by offering optimized storage and querying
> capabilities for embeddings. Vector databases have the capabilities of
> a traditional database that are absent in standalone vector indexes
> and the specialization of dealing with vector embeddings, which
> traditional scalar-based databases lack.
>
> [image: Screenshot Pinecone]

Comment: Your answer is very thorough, thanks!
Thing is I have 2k+ customers who will be asking questions about their own data. Each of these customers could have 100k CRM contacts, 100k jobs completed for these contacts and 100k invoices raised for these jobs etc...
Am I correct to assume Embeddings wouldn't be suitable?
After briefly reading about Llama index it seems to suggest that I would need to duplicate and keep in sync my massive database which doesn't seem feasible. 
This is why I was thinking our using existing API to retrieve data.
I'll update the question to reflect these constraints.

Comment: @Johann You're welcome. :) I haven't tested semantic search on such a large amount of data. But what I'm 99% sure of is that using an API instead of a semantic search is not an option at all. Too expensive, not a good UX, will hallucinate if using function calling, etc. I'm not saying that semantic search would work perfectly in your case, because your concerns might be valid. What I'm trying to tell you is to try googling a bit to learn how to improve semantic search on a large amount of data. But your starting point should be semantic search, not function calling.

Answer (score 1):

Not disagree with the above approach but this is how I would do it - in detail (Only look into this approach if u need a highly reliable answers in your use case otherwise the ROIs are not as great as other solutions).

1. First step I'll do is to identify/figure out what questions the customers are likely to ask. Categorise them into several buckets and assign priorities.
2. For each of the question, define a specific prompt with function call to convert free-form questions into a function.
3. Build a triage prompt to categorise users coming questions.

The user flow will be:

- User asks a question
- Run triage prompt to figure out what category this question is or whether you could handle them
- Use specific prompt to convert the question into runnable function
- Run the function to get data and return to the user.

Ofc this approach requires much more efforts and time but it does do the job much better based on my experience.

Also if you find it painful to manage so many prompts, I've built the tool prompteams.com to help you develop/store/auto-test/version-control the prompts and also create automatic APIs to retrieve prompts.

Let me know if you need further clarification! Good luck!